# Unable to process a file using grunt copy-task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to use grunt-contrib-copy (version 0.4.1) to rewrite some strings inside a file during the build process. As a test I can copy the file, so it's not a permissions or location problem.

These are the options for the fileProcessor task (in Coffeescript syntax) to copy the file:

```
fileProcessor:
    files: [
        expand: true
        cwd: "target/js/"
        dest: "target/js/"
        src: ["**/test-*.js"]
        rename: (dest, src) ->
          grunt.verbose.writeln src, " => ", dest + src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "foo.js"
          dest + src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "foo.js"
    ]
```

I get the following output, everything worked as expected:

```
Running "copy:fileProcessor" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.fileProcessor exists in config...OK
test-25fd6a1c3a890933.js  =>  target/js/foo.js
Files: target/js/test-25fd6a1c3a890933.js -> target/js/foo.js
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Copying target/js/test-25fd6a1c3a890933.js -> target/js/foo.js
Reading target/js/test-25fd6a1c3a890933.js...OK
Writing target/js/foo.js...OK
Copied 1 files
```

So far so good. Clearly grunt-contrib-copy has no problem with the file itself. So I replace the the rename task with a process task, and use a simple regex to see if it works:

```
fileProcessor:
    files: [
        expand: true
        cwd: "target/js/"
        dest: "target/js/"
        src: ["**/test-*.js"]
        processContent: (content, src) ->
            re = new RegExp("(angular)+")
            content.replace(re, "foo")
    ]
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Running "copy:fileProcessor" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.fileProcessor exists in config...OK
Files: target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js -> target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[]
Copying target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js -> target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js
Reading target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js...OK
Writing target/working/shared/scripts/bootstrap-25fd6a1c3a890933.js...OK
Copied 1 files
```

So grunt-contrib-copy finds the file I need to process, but the processing never happens. processContent remains set to the default false.

Looking in copy.js, when `grunt.file.copy(src, dest, copyOptions)` is called, copyOptions is an object with only two properties:

- process, which is false, and
- noProcess, which is an empty array.

So my process options are never passed along. Any ideas on why this could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your processContent is in the wrong place, it needs to be wrapped into options and moved one level higher. Also note that processContent is depreciated and replaced by process

```
fileProcessor:
    files: [
        expand: true
        cwd: "target/js/"
        dest: "target/js/"
        src: ["**/test-*.js"]
    ]
    options: 
        process: (content, src) ->
            re = new RegExp("(angular)+")
            content.replace(re, "foo")
```

Comment: code has so many errors and not easily understable. Could you please modify it?

Comment: which part do you not understand? what errors are you experiencing?

Comment: sorry, Kushal. I don't think I can help if you don't provide more detail